# How to remove a file called * (asterisk) without using quotations?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I implemented the following command to create a file called `*` (asterisk):

```
 echo > '*'
```

Now I'm supposed to remove this file without using any quotations.

I know how to remove this by using quotations, but not sure how without using quotations.

I tried the following commands which I was sure that they won't work because of command line expansion:

```
rm ./*
rm /*
```

If someone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Remove it the same way you created it `rm '*'` or `rm \*`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any quotations @Inian

Comment: `\ ` is not a quote, but it will similarly prevent expansion.

Comment: @Amadan `\ ` shows up under ["Quoting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the Bash manual, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. "There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single quotes, and double quotes." A backslash is not a quote (noun), though it does quote (verb). You can spoon (verb) soup into your mouth with a shot glass; but a shot glass is not a spoon (noun).

Comment: @Amadan I'd argue if the OP isn't allowed to use "quoting", then they aren't allowed to use backslashes either, but I haven't seen the assignment.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Indeed, neither have I. The OP doesn't mention "quoting", only "quotations" (which I take to mean "quotes", but who knows.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're supposed to work this out yourself :-)

The simplest solution not involving quoting is to use the pattern `[*]`. Bracket expressions in a shell work much like character classes in regular expressions so that will match a file whose name is the single character `*`. Thus, you can delete your file with

```
rm [*]
```

Note that you cannot use that pattern to *create* a file named `*` because the shell substitutes words containing patterns with the name(s) of the files *which match the pattern*; if no such file exists, then the pattern is not matched and no substitution is performed. So if there is no file named `*`, then `touch [*]` will create a file named `[*]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction). If the `rm` command directly follows the `echo` command, you can use [`!$`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators):

```
echo > '*'
rm !$
```

`!$` is shorthand for `!!:$`: repeat the last word (`$`) of the last command (`!!`).

If there are commands between the `echo` and the `rm` command, you can find the history number using [`fc -l`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-fc):

```
$ echo > '*'
$ cmd1
$ cmd2
$ cmd3
$ fc -l
[...]
27628    echo > '*'
27629    cmd1
27630    cmd2
27631    cmd3
$ rm !27628:$
```

`!27628` expands to the command with that number in the history, and `$` is again the last word of that command.

If you have to run this in a script, you can't really look up the command number and insert it, but you can count the number of commands between the `echo` and the `rm` and use a relative event designator:

```
echo > '*'
cmd1
rm !-2:$
```

where `!-2` refers to the command two lines back. Notice that history expansion is by default disabled in non-interactive shells; use

```
shopt -o history
```

to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rm -i *` if the number of files is not too big. This will ask for confirmation for every single file. Confirm deletion only for the file `*` and reject it for all others.